# Reminder in Laravel 5.2 scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, scheduler

I want to create a reminder app with Laravel 5.2. It should allow a user to create a reminder and then run a scheduler every minute looking for the nearest reminder field. Then it should notify the user of the reminder by email 15 minutes of 5 minutes or 30 minutes before the time that they have an appointment, just like a reminder on iPhone's.

Does anyone know how to create this functionality with Laravel 5.2?

Comment: You can use [Laravel Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the CRUD for the reminders, so you can have it stored in the database.
Then you have to schedule one command to send the emails. Take a look at the [Laravel Task Scheduling documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) and to the "[Managing Cronjobs with Laravel](https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-cronjobs-with-laravel/)" tutorial.